# Query mongodb documents in loopback

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs

Im trying to query children documents but it throws following error.

Error: Cannot call Project.find(). The find method has not been setup. The PersistedModel has not been correctly attached to a DataSource!

I can see only project documents in explorer, i want to see its children sub documents users too.

project.json

```js
{
  "name": "Project",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "description": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "user": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "User",
      "foreignKey": "userId"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

project.js

```js
'use strict';

module.exports = function(Project) {


Project.find().then((projects => console.log(projects))).catch((err) => console.log(err));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code to be:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(Project) {


Project.find().exec().then((projects => console.log(projects))).catch((err) => 
console.log(err));
};
```

I added .exec() to the query.

Answer (score 0):

The `Model.js` file is not really for executing things (though it's possible if you use [events](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Customizing-models.html#via-your-models-script)).
The server has not been started up yet, datasources haven't been connected to models yet.  The only information which you have access to and can customize are the properties of that one model.

If you want do things on startup put the script in the `server/boot` directory.

`server/boot/project.js`

```
 module.exports = (server) => {

      const Project = server.models.Project;
      Project.find().then((projects => console.log(projects))).catch((err) => console.log(err))
 }
```

Comment: Hi, Its clear, but could you tell me how to retrieve sub documents. router.get('/getprojs', function(req,res){
    Project.find({include: {
      relation: 'user', // include the owner object
      scope: { // further filter the owner object
        fields: ['username', 'email'], // only show two fields 
      }
    }}).then((projects) => res.status(200).send(projects)).catch((err) => res.end(err));
  })

Comment: I have a relation named user, wants to display username and email from it, but i cant see those value but i can still see the userId value. userId is the foreignkey in project.json (model).

Comment: Can you edit that into your question, or ask a new one?  I'm not sure if you're asking how to include sub documents with the user, or trying to see certain fields from an included model.